# RabbitMQ_Broker Status

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have a rabbitmq broker(v3.8) runnung and want to monitor its current status.For eaxmple if accidentally it is stopped , I can run it via monitor program.
Can anybody help please.
My language preference is c# mainly to build the monitor application.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to monitor the rabbitmq status you can use:

- HTTP API https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api
  or
- Prometheus https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html